# Fetch multiple entities with relation between them with one NSFetchedResultController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have base class `Worker` and subclasses `Employee`, `Bookkeeper` and `Director` and entities for them in `xcdatamodeld`. 
Now I want to use `NSFetchedResultController` to fetch them into `tableView` so that each entity in each section.
I dont know how to do that with single frc.
Any help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSFetchedResultsController and Entity Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620954/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-entity-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSFetchedResultsController` can only work with one entity at a time. that will be ok for you since your classes inherit from the worker entity but you are not able to supply a keypath that can determine the subtype which would be used for the sections. The solution I would suggest would be to add a type attribute to the `Worker` entity which could be a simple as an `Int` and then in each subclass set the value during the initialisation to be a different value for each type. Eg.

```
directorInstance.type = 1
```

...

```
employeeInstatnce.type = 2
```

Then define your NSFetchedResultsController:

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Worker")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName contains[cd] %@", nameSearchTerm)
var frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "type", cacheName: nil)
```

Comment: i have a new question beacause of your answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827064/nsfetchedresultscontroller-section-number-is-0 and i dont know for what here is the predicate?

Comment: The predicate is optional but if you don't have it you'll always get back everything for given entity.